# Prestashop Error In Order Returns

Tags: prestashop, object-model

I'm getting an errror in Back Office > Orders > Merchandise Returns when trying to change the return status from "Waiting for Confirmation" to "Waiting for Package".

I've attached screenshots. Any help would be much appreciated. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can't say the exact problem that why it is showing that error. But let me give you a quick fix and hopefully it will fix it. 
Open the file **classes/order/OrderReturn.php**  there find out the below code

```
 public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'order_return',
    'primary' => 'id_order_return',
    'fields' => array(
        'id_customer' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
        'id_order' =>       array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
        'question' =>       array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isMessage'),
        'state' =>          array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
        'date_add' =>       array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),
        'date_upd' =>       array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),
    ),
);
```

There you can see the below line

```
 'question' =>      array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isMessage'),
```

change the it to

```
  'question' =>         array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isString'),
```

And then check the page, hopefully you will have no errors.

Let me know if you still need more help.

Thank you